# AvalonDock 2: LayoutAnchorable IsVisible property not working from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock

I am trying to set the Visibility of `(Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorable) LayoutAnchorable` from XAML like below,

```
<xcad:LayoutAnchorable IsVisible="False" x:Name="Search">
    <Views:SearchPanel DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
```

This is not working but if i try it in `code behind` like below it works.

```
Search.IsVisible = false;
```

Then i created an Attached Property like below,

```
using System.Windows;

namespace ecclient.viewer.Utility
{
public class ELayoutAnchorable
{
    static Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorable LAobj;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Visibility", typeof(bool),typeof(ELayoutAnchorable), new UIPropertyMetadata(true, VisibilityPropertyChanged));

    private static void VisibilityPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LAobj = d as Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorable;
        if(LAobj!=null)
        {
            LAobj.IsVisible = (bool)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
    public static bool GetVisibility(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(VisibilityProperty);
    }
    public static void SetVisibility(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(VisibilityProperty, value);
    }
}
}
```

xaml looks now like below,

```
 <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Utility:ELayoutAnchorable.Visibility="False" >
     <Views:SearchPanel DataContext="{Binding}"/>
 </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
```

`VisibilityPropertyChanged` will be called and sets the `IsVisibile` to `false` is not giving any impact, Is there any way i can avoid code behind to make the visibility false ?